# 2011 Olaskian riddle. [Fictional]

Tags: riddle, language

In the 2011 Olaskia, Jonathan woke up in the morning, ate his homemade breakfast, and drank 4 cups of water. Jonathan discovered some odd riddle-like message in the bottom of his refrigerator, the riddle message was in an obsolete and obscure language and it said:

"Yah Orang-orang undangan ramai,

Galau ramai, angin nak dongeng, mari asal.

Waktu istirahat lama libur.

Domba istirahat enak, Tepuk emas nasi yogut enak abang rasa sapi,

lapar adik, tampilkan enak rasa.

Ndari Wong Abang-Ireng"

What did the riddle actually say? How is it obscure?!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I did some grammar edits, if they mess with you riddle at all just do a rollback and it will go back to the way it was.

Answer (score 5):

Probably, the answer is:

> **Y**ah **O**rang-orang **U**ndangan **R**amai,
> **G**alau **R**amai, **A**ngin **N**ak **D**ongeng, **M**ari **A**sal.
> **W**aktu **I**stirahat **L**ama **L**ibur.
> **D**omba **I**stirahat **E**nak, **T**epuk **E**mas **N**asi **Y**ogut **E**nak **A**bang **R**asa **S**api,
> **L**apar **A**dik, **T**ampilkan **E**nak **R**asa.
> **YOUR GRANDMA WILL DIE TEN YEARS LATER** 
> Well, is the grammar proper or not?

Comment: There's one more line... does it mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

New partial answer based off of @JonathanHalls's answer

Jonathan figuered out:

> Based on the initials of the riddle portion, he came up with "YOUR GRANDMA WILL DIE TEN YEARS LATER". But he never figured out how the last sentence relates.

What I figured out:

> if you translate the last sentence from Javanese to English, back to Javanese, and back to English again, you get "Investigate people". The riddle is asking for you to find out who is trying to kill your grandma.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Halss has already solved most of the puzzle, except the last line

> The message appears to be in Indonesian, I recognise Orang means man, as in Orang-utan. I put it through Google Translate section by section, using a dictionary for certain words that seemed wrong

so

> Well people, noisy invitation,
>  Confusion noisy, wind up story, let's go.
>  Break time long vacation.
>  Sheep break tasty, Golden pat rice, tasty yogut, brother flavored beef,
>  Hungry sister, show good taste.

after that

> final line **"Ndari Wong Abang-Ireng"** I think this may not be Indonesian, the words have meanings in Malay, Javanese and Indonesian it seems.
>  **Ndari** means "no" in Malay according to Google, but **dari** means "from" in all 3 languages. "From..." is a more normal way to sign a letter
>  **Wong** means "person" in Malay/Java
>  **Abang** means "brother" seems to be an honorific or term of respect for an older person
>  **Ireng** means "black" in Malay/Java
>  literally "From black person brother"
>  but idiomatically "From The Black Guy" (maybe)

and

> Jonathan Halss has already found the acrostic. I assume the choice of words is effectively random, just to make the first letters spell out a hidden message. Thus the confusing translation. The final line is not part of the code, but is just a signature.